# android:fixed frame rate animation

Tags: android, animation, frame-rate

I use GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY mode to update my glSurfaceView.

To draw smooth animations I need some controller which will update surface view at a constant frame-rate.I know I can achieve this with Looper class, but I believe there have to be native way of doing this.Ideally I need something like:

```
 Animation anim=new Animation(..);
 anim.setListener(this);
 anim.start();
 ...
private void onNextFrame(float pos) {
 //do my animation according to position value
}
private void onAnimFinished() {
//animation is finished
}
```

**UPD:** Solved, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with the following Class:

```
package tween_test;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class Tween extends Thread {
      public interface OnTweenUpdate {
          public void onNextFrame(Tween tween,float position);
          public void onTweenFinish(Tween tween);
      }
      public enum Easing {
          REGULAR;
      }
      public enum Types {
          LINEAR(1000, false,Easing.REGULAR);
          private final long duration;
          private final boolean looped;
          private final Easing easing;
          Types(long duration, boolean looped,Easing easing) {
              this.duration = duration;
              this.looped = looped;
              this.easing=easing;
          }
          public Easing easing() {
              return this.easing;
          }
          public long duration() {
              return this.duration;
          }
          public boolean looped() {
        return looped;
    }
}
      private final int FPS=60;
      private final int FRAME_DELTA=1000/FPS;
      private long lastFrameTimestamp;
      private OnTweenUpdate listener;
      private Types type;
      private long startTS;
      public Tween(Types type) {
          super();
          this.type=type;
      }
      public void setListener(OnTweenUpdate listener) {
          this.listener=listener;
      }
      @Override
      public void start() {
          lastFrameTimestamp=startTS=SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
          super.start();
      }
      @Override
      public void run() {
          while (!isInterrupted()) {
              long cts= SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
              if (cts-lastFrameTimestamp>=FRAME_DELTA) {
                  lastFrameTimestamp=cts;
                  if (listener!=null)
                      listener.onNextFrame(this,ease((float)(cts-startTS)/type.duration()));
              }
              if(cts>=startTS+type.duration()) {
                  boolean looped=type.looped();
                  if (!looped) {
                      if (listener != null)
                          listener.onTweenFinish(this);
                      this.interrupt();
                  } else {
                      lastFrameTimestamp=startTS=cts;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      public void fforward() {
          if (listener!=null)
              listener.onTweenFinish(this);
          this.interrupt();
      }
      private float ease(float pos) {
          switch (type.easing()) {
              case REGULAR:
                  return  pos;
          }
          return 0f;
      }
}
```

Comment: The solution really should be described in an answer (not the question) - it's perfectly valid to add an answer to your own question and then accept it if you found the solution. Also, this isn't really an answer, it's commentary on another post.

Comment: I didn't post it in the comment as I don't know how to post code in the comment.Few spaces before the code don't work.Code keyword doesn't work either.For example 'code'(this is my code)

Comment: Why do you think the code which solves problem in the starting post is not an answer?